# change dropbox background on reset

Tags: jquery

I have a group of drop down boxes that as a value is used in 1 box, it is   disabled and the background of the value changes to grey in the other boxes. This works fine. My problem is when I reset the form, the backgrounds don't return to white and the values stay disabled. I am using the normal input type='reset" to clear the form
This is the function I use to change the backgrounds

```
function CheckSelected() {
    $(document).on('change', 'select', function () {
        $('option[value="disabled"]').prop('disabled', false);
        $(this).addClass('exception');
        $('option[value="' + this.value + '"]:not(.exception *)').prop('disabled', true);
        $('option[value="' + this.value + '"]:not(.exception *)').css('background-color', 'grey');
        $(this).removeClass('exception');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen to form reset event and reset the background color there:

```
$(document).on('reset', 'form', function() {
    $(this).find('option').css('background-color', '');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/262ro32y/1/

You could also remove the style attribute instead of setting the background color to an empty string:

```
$(this).find('option').removeAttr('style');
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply and help. Your response really helped

Comment: You're welcome. If you think this is the correct answer to your question, please accept it.

Comment: The dropdown boxes all have the same values and when selected he background does change and the value is disabled in the other dropdowns. The reset you suggested works very nice. I have a button that randomly selects a value for the drop downs (which works fine) but the backgrounds don't change when the random button is used, only when each dropdown is selected. Is there a 1 or 2 line code that would change the background as the random function is applying the value to the drop down

Comment: Do you mean that the reset doesn't change the backgrounds back to white if the options are selected with the random button? If so, you are probably using a css class to apply the style. Because the code in my answer removes the background color from all options inside the form, but it doesn't affect the style applied with a class.

Comment: Hmm. Or did you mean that the change event doesn't fire if you change the selected option programmatically? If that's the case, then you can simply trigger the event manually: `$('select').trigger('change');`. Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/262ro32y/6/).

Comment: sorry to confuse you - the reset works perfectly. The function of selecting a value in the dropdown works great as well as the reset code you gave me to use. While I have someone who knows what they are doing I thought I might add my other situation to the mix. On the form I have a random button that sets the values in the drop down boxes ok. What that function doesn't do is change the background of the values used. The values are applied and the background stays white (as expected). What I would like the random routine to also change the background while its doing its thing. T

Comment: I just noticed your demo - I think there is code in the demo that I can reference to get my random routine to do what I want it to do - Thanks